# How can i speed up a np.linsolve method for a pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, lambda

I've currently got a Datafame, which looks like this:

| Account1 | Account2 | Name | Surname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 150 | 18 | Peter | Müller |
| 130 | 1200 | Hans | Zimmer |
| 150 | 18 | Franz | Joseph |
| 106 | 1200 | Joe | Trump |
| 150 | 18 | Christoph | Walz |
| 170 | 1200 | Anne | Will |
| 150 | 138 | Lucenci | Hart |
| 1056 | 1200 | Defig | Iano |

I'm now trying to find a value `m` that would result in a perfect solution for the function:

```
 for x in range(len(data)):
            Account1 = data.loc[x, 'Account1']
            Account2 = data.loc[x, 'Account2']
            m = 1

            a = np.array([[-Account2 - m * Account1]])
            b = np.array([[-Account2 * Account1 + (Account1 ** 2) * m]])
            solution = ((np.linalg.solve(a, b)))
            data.loc[x, "m_solution"] = solution[0]
```

So that it would return:

| m_solution |
| --- |
| -117.857 |
| 104.586 |
| -117.857 |
| 88.793 |
| -117.857 |
| 127.810 |
| -6.25 |
| 67.404 |

This does work completely fine, but for df's with over 50000 rows, it takes pretty long.

Is there a way to optimize this using something like lambda or are there maybe already pandas functions that could solve something like this in no time?

Comment: Am I right in deducing that `a` and `b` are both (1,1) arrays?  So the first number is just `(-18*150+(150**2)*1)/(-18-1*150)`?  Why are you using `linsolve` for simple division?

Comment: Try setting `Account1 = data['Account1']` etc, and doing the above calculation for all rows at once.  I don't think you need to iterate on rows, nor use `linsolve`.  It's just a simple calculation from the values of two Series.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented:

```
In [80]: Account1 = df['Account1']
    ...: Account2 = df['Account2']
    ...: m = 1
    ...: a = -Account2 - m * Account1
    ...: b = -Account2 * Account1 + (Account1 ** 2) * m
    ...: solution = b/a
    ...: df["m_solution"] = solution
In [81]: df
Out[81]: 
   Account1  Account2  m_solution
0       150        18 -117.857143
1       130      1200  104.586466
2       150        18 -117.857143
3       106      1200   88.793262
4       150        18 -117.857143
5       170      1200  127.810219
6       150       138   -6.250000
7      1056      1200   67.404255
```